# lite youtube: youtube video embed end listener, For example I want to play another video after it, but "end" parameter is not for that use

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, addeventlistener

I want another embed video to play automatically after the end of another using lite-yt-embed.js. I am trying to study how to get exact end parameter of a youtube video embed, but I think "end" parameter is only used in modifying what time you want the video to end.
Lite youtube js link:
https://github.com/paulirish/lite-youtube-embed

This is what was stated in the developers.google:
end: This parameter specifies the time, measured in seconds from the start of the video, when the player should stop playing the video. The parameter value is a positive integer.

I have tried using "end" parameter, it really just modifies the time of the end of the video.
I am trying to learn to make video end listener, but the parameter was not stated in https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: I am going to use .click() to trigger the click if the other video ended

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.